# Reverse Proxy PHP

Tags: php, proxy, reverse

I want to develop software that will allow people to log in and pay a bill.  The software will have to connect to a server hosted at a client (could be many clients) and retrieve some information.  The issue is that I want to make it work in any scenario.  Similar to the home remote control software like goto my pc.  I have no gurantee of the setup for the client only that they have a windows based server and and internet connection.  I would like to install a piece of software and have it connect to the server and wait for information.  I really would like to use the simplest software possible such as PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this what websites were invented for?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your comment?

Comment: Robert, your question is very vague and general, so ceejayoz gave you a very vague and general answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to develop software that will allow people to log in and pay a bill.

That is a requirement. That is fine.

> The software will have to connect to a server hosted at a client (could be many clients) and retrieve some information.

That is a specific technical solution to the above requirement. And not a very good one I might add.

So. Do you want to know how best to solve your requirement, or do you want a technical explanation about how you could implement your (totally misguided) proposed solution?